# Change Audio tag user agent CSS

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, html5-audio

I would like to edit the native HTML audio tag but for that I have to use jquery and mediaelement libraries to achieve that:

```
//https://codepen.io/tomma5o/pen/jAKQYz

$('audio').mediaelementplayer({
   features: ['playpause','progress','current','tracks','fullscreen']
});
```

I am new with react so what do you think, does it have big impact in the performance of react adding jquery library in that case?

EDITED

```
&::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
&::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button,
&::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display,
&::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
   display: none;
}
```

But to hide the download button it does not work

```
&::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
   display: none !important;
}
```

[image: DevTools->Elements]

I also have the same problem with the track-segment CSS, I cannot style each segment background color.

My audio looks like that...

[image]

Comment: Newer versions of the plugin do not require jQuery, and they also provide code on how to use it with React (https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/usage.md#react)

Comment: Thanks! But I have found another solution that it is easier just editing the user agent css. Edited above